# x509 error when trying to login to a trusted (?) docker registry

Tags: ssl, docker, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, docker-registry

I have set up a docker registry using harbor.

I have copied the appropriate certificates in `/usr/share/local/ca-certificates` and run `sudo update-ca-certificates` with success. (indicated the number of newly certs added).

When trying to login to the specific registry:

```
ubuntu@master1:/home/vagrant$ docker login my.registry.url
Username: pkaramol
Password: 
Error response from daemon: Get https://my.registry.url/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

However the following test succeeds:

```
openssl s_client -connect my.registry.url:443 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/
```

...coming back with a lot of verbose output, the certificate itself and ending in :

```
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

`curl` also succeeds to the above `https` link (it fails when the site is not trusted).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation

### Use self-signed certificates

> Warning: Using this along with basic authentication requires to also trust the certificate into the OS cert store for some versions of docker (see below)
>   This is more secure than the insecure registry solution.

Generate your own certificate:

```
$ mkdir -p certs

$ openssl req \
  -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -keyout certs/domain.key \
  -x509 -days 365 -out certs/domain.crt
```

Be sure to use the name myregistrydomain.com as a CN.

Use the result to start your registry with TLS enabled.

Instruct every Docker daemon to trust that certificate. The way to do this depends on your OS.

**Linux:** Copy the `domain.crt` file to `/etc/docker/certs.d/myregistrydomain.com:5000/ca.crt` on every Docker host. You do not need to restart Docker.

See below link for more details

https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#use-self-signed-certificates

Comment: Does this mean registries work only with self-signed certificates? The ones I am using are not self signed, just for the record.

Comment: Turns out it just needed a restart after the addition of the certificates... the idea from this github comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8849#issuecomment-70595191